# How to define UpValues of NBSpline when the length of argument is unknown?

Tags: programming, syntax, code-review

I mimic the *built-in* `BSplineBasis[]` to build a user-defined function `NBSpline[]`, Namely,

- `NBSpline[{deg,knots}, idx, x]`

  > gives the *idx*-th non-uniform B-spline basis function of degree *deg* with *knots* at positions $u_i$.;

where, `knots =`$\{u_1,u_2,\cdots, u_m\}$

The first derivative of B-spline basis function satisfies the following relationship

$$\frac{d}{d u} N_{i,p}(u)=\frac{p}{u_{i+p}-u_i}N_{i,p-1}(u)-\frac{p}{u_{i+p+1}-u_{i+1}}N_{i+1,p-1}(u)$$

where, $N_{i,p}(u)$ denotes the basis of B-spline, and $\vec{U}=\{u_0,u_1,\ldots,u_m\}$, which is a non-decreasing sequence of real numbers,i.e, $u_i\leq u_{i+1}\quad i=0,1,2\ldots m-1$

---

Thank for *Patrick Stevens*'s answer. I revised the code as below:

```
(*the derivative of NBSpline[{deg,{knots}},idx,u]*)
NBSpline /: 
 Derivative[{0, {0,..}}, 0, k_Integer?Positive][NBSpline] :=
 Function[{arg1, idx, u},
  Module[
   {deg, knots, coeffs, body},
   {deg, knots} = arg1;
   coeffs =
    deg/(knots[[# + deg]] - knots[[#]]) & /@ {idx + 1, idx + 2};
   body =
    NBSpline[{deg - 1, knots}, #, u] & /@ {idx, idx + 1};
   D[coeffs.body, {u, k - 1}]
  ]
 ]
```

#### Question

- How to define the `UpValues` about the derivative of `NBSpline` when the length of knots unknow?(Namely, the `knots` is a **input** from user)?

For instance, if I know the length of knots, I can define it like this:

```
(*if the length of knots equals to 9*)
NBSpline /: Derivative[{0, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}}, 0, k_Integer?Positive][NBSpline]
```

However, when I don't know the length of `knots`, I define it as below:

```
NBSpline /: Derivative[{0, {0,..}}, 0, k_Integer?Positive][NBSpline]
```

which cannot pass the syntax of *Mathematica*.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
Function[{args1, var2, var3}, With[{deg = args1[[1]], knots = args1[[2]]},
  code
]]
```

Not the neatest, but it would seem to do the job.